# OpenCV data of two mats are the same but values when retrieved with Mat::at are corrupted

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I serialize and then deserialize a Mat using custom functions. When you compare the `uchar* Mat.data` of two functions they are the same but when I try to check values directly using `Mat.at<>` after third element, element values are stuck at some corrupted float values. I tried changing elements to every other value, nothing changed. The problem also doesn't happen when I serialize-deserialize image Mats and histogram Mats. Below is the code and below that is the output.

```
cv::Mat kernelx = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1);
std::string stroper = dbop::serializeMat(kernelx);
cv::Mat matoper = dbop::deserializeMat(stroper);
for (int i = 0; i < matoper.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matoper.cols; j++) {
        float f1 = (float)kernelx.data[i + j];
        float f2 = (float)matoper.data[i + j];
        std::cout << kernelx.at<float>(i, j) << " " << matoper.at<float>(i, j) << " " << f1 << " " << f2 << " " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the output. First values are elements of the original Mat, second values are elements of serialized-deserialized Mat, third values are the original Mat's data values casted to float, fourth values are s-d Mat's data values.

```
1       1               0       0
0       0               0       0
-1      -4.31596e+08    128     128
1       -4.31602e+08    0       0
0       -4.31602e+08    128     128
-1      -4.31602e+08    63      63
1       -4.31602e+08    128     128
0       -4.31602e+08    63      63
-1      -4.31602e+08    0       0
```

I guess serializeMat and deserializeMat functions are relevant here so here is both.

```
std::string dbop::serializeMat(cv::Mat operand) {
    std::ostringstream srlzstrstream;
    uchar* pixelPtr = (uchar*)operand.data;
    int cn = operand.channels();
    cv::Scalar_<uchar> cnPixel;

    srlzstrstream << operand.dims << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < operand.dims; i++) {
        srlzstrstream << operand.size[i] << " ";
    }
    srlzstrstream << operand.type() << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < operand.total(); i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < cn; k++) {
                srlzstrstream << (float)pixelPtr[i * cn + k] << " ";
            }
    }
    std::string srlzdstr = srlzstrstream.str();
    return srlzdstr;
}
```

```
cv::Mat dbop::deserializeMat(std::string operand){
    std::istringstream desrlzstrstream(operand);
    int mdims, mtype;

    desrlzstrstream >> mdims;
    int* msize = new int[mdims];
    for (int i = 0; i < mdims; i++)
        desrlzstrstream >> msize[i];
    desrlzstrstream >> mtype;

    cv::Mat matoper(mdims, msize, mtype);
    delete [] msize;

    uchar* pixelPtr = (uchar*)matoper.data;
    float cnpixoper;

    for (int i = 0; i < matoper.total(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < matoper.channels(); k++) {
            desrlzstrstream >> cnpixoper;
            pixelPtr[i * matoper.channels() + k] = cnpixoper;
        }
    }
    return matoper;
}
```

Comment: `(float)pixelPtr[i * cn + k]` -- You forget that `uchar` is 1 byte and `float` is 4 bytes. The cast is too late -- you've already read a single byte at wrong position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+ Edit 
Since you want to save byte for generic types, you can just iterate each byte like this.

In `serializeMat`

```
for (int i = 0; i < operand.total() * operand.elemSize(); i++) {
    srlzstrstream << pixelPtr[i] << " ";
}
```

In `deserializeMat`

```
for (int i = 0; i < matoper.total() * matoper.elemSize(); i++) {
    desrlzstrstream >> cnpixoper;
    pixelPtr[i] = cnpixoper;
}
```

`operand.total() * operand.elemSize()` will give you the byte size of `operand`

In both case, the output is

```
   1    1    0    0 
   0    0    0    0 
  -1   -1  128  128 
   1    1    0    0 
   0    0  128  128 
  -1   -1   63   63 
   1    1  128  128 
   0    0   63   63 
  -1   -1    0    0
```

Comment: I want the functions to be general functions that work with all sort of Mats. uchar Mats, float Mats etc. So if this was for example an image Mat with elements of uchar type, what would BIT_RATIO be? Would it be the same?

Comment: @OneBadStudent No it would be different, since `sizezof(float)` is 4, while `sizeof(uchar` is 1. I'll update my answer to work on other types.